# "Today is rainy" Vs. "It's rainy today."

Tags: word-order, time-words

Is it correct to say "**Today** **is** rainy" (or "**Tomorrow** **will be** frost.")?

Normally I mention the time-expression in the end of the sentences as I was taught in past. For example: **It is** rainy **today**. **It will be** frost **tomorrow**.   But in the first examples that I'm asking about them, there's neither subject pronoun nor time-expression in the end. That's why I'm asking my question.

Comment: You should consider how tagging everything you post with “grammar” makes it difficult for people with the same question to find yours, and prevents your question from being brought to the attention of people watching the relevant tags.

Comment: I'm doing it only when I really don't know which tag to put. Normally I don't have problem with that, but sometimes it happens to be:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like,

> Today is a good day. Today is good.

"Rainy" and "good" are both adjectives, so:

> Today is a rainy day. Today is rainy.

But "frost" is a noun, so to make parallel sentences, you would have to use the adjective, "frosty":

> Tomorrow will be a frosty day. Tomorrow will be frosty.

Alternatively, if you want to use the noun "frost", you could say, "Tomorrow *there will be* frost." In the same way you could use the noun "rain". Today there is rain. (In other words "Rain exists.")

It doesn't matter whether the day comes at the beginning or the end --- "Today is rainy." "It is rainy today." --- They both sound good, and equally natural.